# RegEx to capture and replace exact matches, with expressions that might contain special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to create some sort of translation egine.
I am given a mapping of attributes, and using this mapping I need to translate an expression.

For example, I have this mapping:

```
{
  "a": "A",
  "b[*]": "B[*]",
  "c": "C",
  "ac": "D"
}
```

And an example input might be (the rule is that each token can be followed by a `.`, it's actually a JSONPath):

`a.b[*]` should translate to `A.B[*]`

And each input can appear arbitraritly in the expression, for example I can have a mix:
`a.c.b[*]` => `A.C.B[*]`

My solution was to create a list of Regexes out of this mapping, and looping that, searching and replacing the expression for each regex.

The problem was in inputs like that:
`ac` => should have translated to `D` but instead, since there exist mapping for `a` and `c`, their regexes match and I get `AC` instead.

I thought to use word boundaries \b, but it didn't work well in cases there were special chars, like in the `b[*]` example, as it's not included in the word boundary.

I also thought to extend the boundary, but nothing worked as expected.

In the bottom line: is there a way to replace a stirng by another, considering that only a full match is valid, but an expression can be part of a JSONPath string?

Comment: Put longer values first in your alternation (e.g. `ac|a|c`) that will make them match in preference to the shorter ones. https://regex101.com/r/eJ86mj/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try building a regex alternation of the lookup keys.  Then, use `replace()` with a callback function to make the replacements.  As the comment by @Nick above mentions, the alternation should place longer substrings first.

```js
var map = {
    "a": "A",
    "b[*]": "B[*]",
    "c": "C",
    "ac": "D"
};
var input = "a.c.b[*]";
var output = input.replace(/(ac|a|c|b\[\*\])/g, (x, y) => map[y]);
console.log(output);
```

This approach also avoids an ugly explicit loop.

Comment: Yeap, suspected the lenght thing, but wanted to see if maybe there's a less "trivial" solution